# "Differentiability" implies continuity

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ has a derivative $\forall x\in(a,b)$ (including infinite derivatives). Does it imply $f$ being continuous at $[a,b]$ or only at $(a,b)$ or neither?

Comment: continuous at$x\in[a,b]$

Comment: $f(x)=x/|x|$, $x\ne 0$, $f(0)=0$ has derivative $\infty$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks. And if I remove infinite derivatives from my assumptions, what is the answer?

Comment: You can only deduce continuity on the open interval. Take $f(x)=1$, $0\ne x\ne1$; $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a function diff. at $(a,b)$ that isn't continuous at $[a,b]$ - is one-side discontinuous at $a$ or $b$?

Comment: @Klobbbyyy yes one side discontinous.

Comment: $\tan(x)$ differentiable $\forall x\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Not continuous at $x=\pm \pi/2$

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks, I didn't read your whole comment.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Thanks.

Comment: @Klobbbyyy $\lfloor x\rfloor$ works as well.

Answer (score 1):

we can infer this function is continuous at(a,b) but not on the whole interval.

$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)
$$
Using the famous $\epsilon-\delta$ notation to translate the limit:

for any given $\epsilon>0$, however small, we can find a $\delta>0$, such that,

$$
|\frac{f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0)}{\delta}-f'(x_0)|<\epsilon
$$

or

$$
\delta\times (f'(x_0)-\epsilon)<f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0)<\delta\times (f'(x_0)+\epsilon)
$$

now, let $\delta\to 0$
we get

$$f(x_0+\delta)\to f(x_0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Statement holds only for finite derivatives and the open interval (as proven here http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html). The signum function has infinite derivative in $0$ and is discontinuous at that point. The tangens function is differentiable at $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ while being undefined at $\pm\pi/2$. Credit to David Mitra and Sabyasachi.